# Kaplan Meier estimate for data with unequal numbers in treatments

Tags: r, survival, kaplan-meier

Is it possible to estimate Kaplan-Meier medians, CIs and difference with unequal sample size in treatments or do I have to do `coxph`? For example, in my dataset, treatment 1: n=38, treatment 2: n=24.

```
survdiff(formula = Surv(timemale, timemalestat ) ~ treatment, na.action = na.exclude)
                       N Observed Expected (O-E)^2/E (O-E)^2/V
treatment=fast        38       35     22.1      7.53        15
treatment=slow        24       13     25.9      6.42        15
 Chisq= 15  on 1 degrees of freedom, p= 0.000108 

> KMtrav4 <- survfit(Surv(timemale, timemalestat)~treatment, na.action=na.exclude)
               records n.max n.start events median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL
treatment=fast      38    38      38     35   18.5      11      37
treatment=slow      24    24      24     13  131.0      56      NA
```

Comment: If you want to make a comparison with Kaplan-Meier curves, you do not need equal sample sizes. 

Just fyi, the name of the test run with default settings in survdiff is a logrank statistic.